# Calculated Column - IF true AND true

Tags: 2013, calculated-column

Using a task list I am trying to show a value if a cell is = to a certain string, AND task is complete.

Im currently using this but returning a #VALUE error

```
=AND([Task Name]="Task 2",Completed,"1","0")
```

Do i need to use

```
=IF(AND[Task Name]="Task 2",Completed,"1","0")
```

Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(AND([Task Name]="Task 2",Completed),1,0)
```

Figured out with help from Tiac

Answer (score 1):

Try this function, should work.

```
=IF(AND([Task Name]="Task 2;[Status Field Name]="Completed");1;0)
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly returns the errors screen.
=IF(AND([Task Name]="Task 2;[Completed]="Completed");1;0)

Comment: Got a version that works, slightly varied from your suggestion.

=IF(AND([Task Name]="Task 2",Completed),1,0)

Comment: Great! For the future, you can test your calculated formula in excel. It's a little help, because the formula you use in excel are mostly the same as in sharepoint.